# When can we write one function as a non-negative integral of another?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x,y)$ be positive real-valued functions. It is often quite useful to write
$$f(x) = \int g(x,y)\, {\rm d}\mu(y)$$
for some non-negative measure $\mu(y)$. For example, this can be very useful for converting bounds on $g$ into bounds on $f$.

I'm interested in necessary and/or sufficient conditions for when this is possible.

As a simple example, if $f$, $g$, and $\mu$ are nice enough, then if $g(x,y)$ has non-negative Fourier transform in $x$ for all $y$, $f$ must also have non-negative Fourier transform as well.

More generally, let $T_x$ be any linear functional satisfying $\int T_x g(x,y) \,{\rm d} \mu(y) = T_x f(x)$. Then, if $T_x g(x,y)$ is non-negative for all $y$, then $T_x f(x)$ must also be non-negative.

Is this condition sufficient? Are there simpler necessary and/or sufficient conditions?